# Problem about metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

could you help me with the following situation? I have not been able to show it a thousand thanks. Forgive my English.

Let  $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $T$ the topology induced on $X$ by $d$. Let $Y$ be a subset of X and $d_1$ the metric on $Y$ obtained by restricting $d$ that is 
$d_1(a,b)=d(a,b)$  for all $a$ and $b$ in Y. If $τ_1$ is the topology induced on Y by $d_1$ and $τ_2$ is the subspace topology on Y (induced by $T$ on $X$) prove that $τ_1=τ_2$

So thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to show in general that two topologies on a set are the same?

Comment: No. Can you explain me?

Comment: Okay, so if $\tau_1 = \tau_2$, then $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$ and $\tau_2 \subset \tau_1$. In other words, if $U \in \tau_1$, then $U \in \tau_2$ and if $V \in \tau_2$, then $V \in \tau_1$. Another way of saying this is that $U$ is open in $\tau_1$ if and only if $U$ is open in $\tau_2$. Does that give you any idea of how to start?

Comment: No, really i´m so confused. :(

Comment: Do you know what it means for a set to be open in the metric topology? For example, if $U$ is open in the topology $T$ induced on $X$ by $d$, and $x \in U$, then what would that imply?

Comment: x is in an open ball?

Comment: Almost - importantly, $x$ is in an open ball contained in $U$. So suppose now that $U$ is an open set in the topology $\tau_1$ induced by $d_1$ on $Y$. Can you show that $U$ is also open in the subspace topology $\tau_2$ on $Y$ inherited from the topology on $X$?

Comment: This is my problem, can i prove that question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our goal here is to show that $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$ and $\tau_2 \subset \tau_1$.

First, we will show $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$:

Let $U\subset Y$ be open in $\tau_1$. We want to show that $U \in \tau_2$. So we need to show that there exists some $V \in T$ such $U = V \cap Y$. Since $U$ is open in the topology induced by the metric $d_1$ on $Y$, for each $x \in U$, there exists an $\epsilon_x$ such that Ball$_{d_1}(x, \epsilon_x) \subset U$ (meaning the ball of radius $\epsilon_x$ centered at $x$ in the $d_1$ metric on $Y$). Let $V = \bigcup\limits_{x \in U} \text{Ball}_d(x, \epsilon_x)$. Note that each of these open-balls is in the $d$ metric on $X$, so $V$ is open in $X$. Note also that by the definition of $V$, $U \subset V$. We claim that $V \cap Y = U$. If $y \in V \cap Y$, then there exists an $x \in U$ such that $y \in \text{Ball}_d(x, \epsilon_x)$. So $d_1(x,y) = d(x,y) < \epsilon_x$. Thus $y \in \text{Ball}_{d_1}(x, \epsilon_x)\subset U$, so $V \cap Y \subset U$. Also, since $U \subset V$ and $U \subset Y$, $U \subset V \cap Y$. Thus $U = V \cap Y$, so $U$ is open in $\tau_2$. Hence $\tau_1 \subset \tau_2$.

Given this start, can you show $\tau_2 \subset \tau_1$?